# What approximation techniques exist for the square super-root function?

Tags: approximation

I need to implement an approximation to the inverse of $x^x$, i.e. the *square super-root* (ssrt) function. For example, $\mathrm{ssrt}(2) \approx 1.56$ means that $1.56^{1.56} \approx 2$.  I'm not as interested in any particular accuracy/bit-depth as I am in understanding what my options are in contrast to more straightforward approaches using power series.

Wolfram Alpha gives a nice [symbolic solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20x%5Ex) in terms of the Lambert W function (i.e. $\ln(x)/W(\ln(x))$ ).  Wikipedia gives the [same formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Square_super-root), as well as the equivalent $e^{W(\ln(x))}$. Given that there's a reasonable amount of information on computing $W(x)$ [1] [2], technically that's everything needed to implement *something* for a variety of requirements.  I know of at least two books that go into extensive detail about approximating $\ln(x)$ [3] [4], so there's even plenty of room to optimize from that direction.

However, I have two questions:

1. Have approximation techniques specific to this function been published anywhere?
2. Does it go by another name besides "square super-root" that would make searching for references at a little easier?

Wikipedia/Google has turned up some references dedicated to more general "tetration" functions that include $\mathrm{ssrt}(x)$ as a special case, but most of them seem to be more geared to exploring/defining the general cases.

--

1. Corless, R.; Gonnet, G.; Hare, D.; Jeffrey, D.; Knuth, Donald (1996), *"On the Lambert W function"* http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf
2. *Digital Library of Mathematical Functions*. http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13
3. Crenshaw, Jack W. (2000), *Math Toolkit for Real-Time Programming.*
4. Hart, John F. (1978), *Computer Approximations.*
5. Chapeau-Blondeau, F. and Monir, A. (2002). *Numerical evaluation of the Lambert W
   function and application to generation of generalized Gaussian noise with exponent 1/2.* IEEE
   Transactions on Signal Processing 50, 2160-2165. http://www.istia.univ-angers.fr/~chapeau/papers/lambertw.pdf
6. Minero, Paul. *Fast Approximate Lambert W*. http://www.machinedlearnings.com/2011/07/fast-approximate-lambert-w.html

--

**Update**

After doing some more research over the past few days, I still haven't found the kind of hands-on "Crenshaw style" $[3]$ treatment of $\mathrm{ssrt}(x)$ I was hoping for, but I did find a new reference worth documenting here.  On page three in $[5]$, there's a section titled "Fast Approximation" that goes into great detail about approximating $W(x)$ in the context of noise generation. As an interesting aside, the probability density of "Gaussian noise with exponent 1/2" [in the paper] looks strikingly similar to the histogram in [Kellenjb](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/17/kellenjb)'s answer to [this question about detecting signal clipping](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/65/what-are-good-ways-to-detect-signal-clipping-in-a-recording).

In addition, the link given by [rwong](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/58/rwong) in the comments $[6]$ is a great resource for actually implementing $W(x)$, and it even links to the author's BSD licensed project called [fastapprox](http://code.google.com/p/fastapprox/), which includes the implementation described.

Comment: http://www.machinedlearnings.com/2011/07/fast-approximate-lambert-w.html

Comment: I asked about this on Meta, since the comments field isn't meant for extended discussions. Please suggest how we should handle these questions here: [Are questions on numerical analysis on-topic?](http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36/are-questions-on-numerical-analysis-on-topic)

Comment: @datageist - The initial conclusion from the meta question was that if you  want to use this numerical analysis to process DSP data, then it's on-topic.  If not, then not.  How does this relate to DSP?

Comment: @Kevin It came up in the context of developing an audio effect.

Comment: Over what range of values are you trying to approximate?  x**x is not monotonic, so an inverse mapping does not really exist.  e.g. 0**0 == 1, 1**1 == 1.  You could limit it to values of x > 1/e, above which it is monotonic

Comment: @Mark, I'm just interested in "the values that make sense", most likely real values in the range [e^(-1/e), e^(-1/e) + 2] (cf. http://bit.ly/paiCIr ).  It's easy enough to come up with something, I'm just hoping someone out there already spent a month or so thinking about it and published something cooler than the straightforward approach.

Comment: Whenever I need to write a routine for the Lambert function, I usually use the approximations given in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.90.6481) and then polish up with Newton-Raphson, Halley, or any other iterative method. You could adapt this approach for inverting $x^x$...

Comment: @datageist I am curious, what signal processing application are/were you working with that needed you to compute a super square root?

Answer (score 6):

Some numerical stabs in the dark yielded the following for an iterative approach:

We're looking for the solution y = f(x) where y^y = x.

$$y \ln y = \ln x$$

$$y = g(x,y) = e^{\frac{\ln x}{y}}$$

The value for $y$ is a fixed point of the above equation, and empirically it seems to converge for some values of $x$, but for larger values of $x$ it oscillates or diverges.

Then I tried an approach similar to Newton's iterative square-root:

$$y = \frac{y_{previous} + y_{*}}{2} = \frac{y + e^{\frac{\ln x}{y}}}{2}$$

where y* is supposed to represent a nonconverging but optimistic answer that maintains accuracy if you happen to guess an accurate initial value (in square root y<sup>2</sup> = x, it's y* = x/y).

This appears to converge, but very slowly at the low end of $x$ (near $x_{min} = (\frac{1}{e})^{\frac{1}{e}}$ )

It also looks like a good initial guess is $y_0 = \ln(x)+1$.

So I figured maybe there's a better-converging solution:

$y = (1-a) \times y + a \times g(x,y)$ for some value of $a$ that is a function of $x$.

Then I found something interesting.

If I get a converging answer $y$ from the above approach for $y^y = x$, and then compute $y_2 = g(x,y+ \epsilon) = e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{y+\epsilon}}$, it *appears* as though $y_2-y$ = approximately $\epsilon \times (-\ln(y))$.... e.g. if we had a guess $y_1 = y + \epsilon$ for some unknown $\epsilon$, and computed $y_2 = g(x,y_1)$, then $(y_2 - y) \approx \epsilon \times (-\ln(y)) = (y_1 - y) \times (-\ln(y))$. (Just to clarify, I have no analysis to verify this, but the numbers just popped out of some numerical evaluation I performed.)

Solve for the linear terms in $y$, and you get $y = \dfrac{y_2 + \ln(y) \times y_1}{1 + \ln(y)}$... use $\ln(y_1)$ in place of $\ln(y)$ and you get this iterative approximation:

$$\begin{align*}
    y[n+1] &= \frac{g(x,y[n]) + \ln(y[n])\times y[n]}{1+\ln(y[n])}\\
           &= \frac{e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{y[n]}} + \ln(y[n])\times y[n]}{1+\ln(y[n])}
\end{align*}$$

This appears to work very well, with the initial guess $y = 1+\ln(x)$, and appears to converge within 4 or 5 iterations.

(Someone could probably show that this is equivalent to Newton-Raphson in some way, but I think it's beyond my capability.)