# Return list of wav files in folder that are clipped

Tags: wave

Is there any method via python of any other means, to return a list of wav files in a folder that are clipped?

I know that Adobe Audition can tell if a file is clipped, but I have to open up each file and then check.  Can this process be automated somehow?  Any direction is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate: [What are good ways to detect signal clipping in a recording?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/65/what-are-good-ways-to-detect-signal-clipping-in-a-recording)

Comment: @Jdip, thanks for your suggestion.  I checked out the link but it does not state how to look at the files from a batch level to automatically return if the file is clipped or not.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: That’s a programming question then, not a signal processing one.

Comment: Can't you just loop over all files in a directory or  file list? I don't think I understand what your problem with "batch mode " is

Comment: @Hilmar, I have an idea to loop over the files, but I'm not sure what to loop. That is, is there a specific command I can use to check for clipping?

Comment: @Jdip, you are referring to the accepted answer in your link?

Comment: Orban Loudness meter has some good tools but, dunno if it detects cllpping only. https://www.orban.com/meter , https://www.orban-europe.com/downloads/Orban_Loudness_Meter/Documentation/FreeOrbanLoudnessMeter_2.9.7.pdf

Comment: I would use `sox in.wav -n stats`, grep for "Pk lev dB" and "Pk count". If "Pk lev dB" is 0 dBFS and "Pk count" is greater than 2, then there might be clipping present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what @jojek suggests, With sox it is quite easy to find clipped audio files:

```
for i in *; do echo $i `sox $i -n --norm -R gain 0.1 2>&1`; done |grep clipped
```

lists audio files with clipping.

*Notice: It's not exact so "gain 0.1" (in decibels) is suggestion to catch anything *almost* clipping just to be on the safe side. You might want to leave that out or tweak the gain.*

To check all files in one step you could use script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . | while read LINE
do
 sox "$LINE" -n --norm -R gain 0.1 2>&1 | grep clipped && echo "$LINE"
done
```

Same notice as with the 1st script.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  Is it possible to convert your code to `batch` formatting?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, but I have not played with batch files for years now. In generally speaking you just need to loop the sox command for audio files. Scripting languages (VBScript, JScript) works in this too and you should be well with entering sox commands directly to command prompt as well  http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html , https://madskjeldgaard.dk/posts/sox-tutorial-batch-processing/